# ReadAllText not Reading all text from a file

Tags: search, size, limit, out-of-memory

I have a program that searches using ReadAllText from a file. The file is only 2.2meg. It reads about 80% and does not give an error. It just does not find my searches in the 20% extra text. What can i do. using c#. Thanks

Comment: post your code, it may help us to identify error

Comment: I just did a search on a 64meg file. It read all but 20%.

Comment: `string str = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\PC2.BIN");
                    Regex reg = new Regex("333333", RegexOptions.Multiline); // save incase of change "333333"
                    Match sat = reg.Match(str);
                    while (sat.Success)
                    {
                        textBox3.Text += (sat.Index -24 + " " + "\r\n"); //shows index where 333333 is
                        sat = reg.Match(str, sat.Index + sat.Length);

                        
                }
            }`

Comment: i will write it to read in reverse also and take out the duplicate finds.